# Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). Error

Tags: php, foreach, error-log

Invalid argument supplied for foreach () error

Hello, I have the following problem on my website, when I check the file "error_log" this em shows the following error:

*"Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/ ..."*

It is in the error location:

```
  <?php                                       

        foreach ($on['result'] as $val) { ?>

            <a href="#" onClick="goToProfile(<?= $val['id'];?>)"><li class="chat__human" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">

                <img class="chat__avatar" style="padding: 1px;margin:3px" src="<?= $val['photo'];?>" alt="" />

                <span class="chat__name comforta" style="position: absolute;margin-left:5px;margin-top: 5px;font-weight: bold"><?= $val['firstName'];?></span>

                <span class="chat__last_m" style="position: absolute;margin-left:5px;margin-top: 23px;color:#999"> <?= $val['last_m'];?></span>

            </li></a>             

        <?php } ?>
```

I hope you can help me solve this error, thank you.

Comment: **what is print_f($on['result'] );**?

Comment: `$on['result']` is probably not set or not an array.

Comment: <?php 
    $query = 'id='.$sm['user']['id'];
    $action = 'getOnlineFriends';
    $on = apiCall($action,$query);
?>

Comment: if you do a var_dump() on $on, what do you get?

Comment: Nothing and the error persists